# Окна в перехватывают и блокируют sendinput из ahk

Tags: autohotkey

Окна в Windows 10 перехватывают sendinput (особенно Visual Studio) и переопределяют следующий скрипт:

```
F1 :: 
    If (A_TimeSincePriorHotkey < 100) ;hyperclick
    Return
    sendinput {LButton down}
    KeyWait, LButton
    sendinput {LButton up}
    Return
```

В результате в редакторе кода не работает F1 как щелчок мыши при нажатии, есть у кого-нибудь какие-нибудь идеи, как всё-таки забиндить макрос на эту клавишу и чтобы окна не реагировали на событие нажатия этой кнопки, если в скрипте ahk она уже описана?

Что-нибудь вроде метода *PreventDefault*?

Answer (score 0):

В общем в той же студии можно автоматически отключить назначенные клавиши на быстрый доступ к справке (не уверен, что это можно сделать где-то ещё), но частично это решило проблему.

Просто жмём Remove напротив Shortcut for selected command.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]